# Simulating key press to another process PID in linux using a python script

Tags: linux, python

So I am running a process like ssh or telnet session in linux and controlling it through one python script. I want to simulate ctrl+d using the script such that I am able to log out through the script. The problem is that i need to uninstall the OS through onie so i will not be able to use xdotool also. If anyone have any answer please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does "controlling it" mean here, *precisely*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Controlling here means removing the onl image and installation of new onl image.

Comment: what is an onl image? What is your *method* of controlling that process? Basically, you're not showing us what you're doing, so we can't really tell you how to solve your problem.

Comment: open network linux image

Comment: Basically I have logged into a telnet session to a device . And I am running a python script which is giving commands to this telnet process using a .fifo file . normal commands like ls cd etc i am able to give to telnet session easily through this .fifo file but not able to give keyboard key presses through this .fifo file.

Comment: do you mean a FIFO (also known as "named pipe"), or do you mean a file?